# Problemas al acceder a servidor Wildfly 8

Tags: java, webservice, jboss, wildfly

Tengo una aplicación web la cual utilizo un servidor Wildfly 8 para distribuír. Accediendo a la aplicación desde el servidor, osea, localhost, me reconoce sin problema y levanta la aplicación, pero cuando trato de acceder desde una pc conectada a la red no reconoce esa aplicación, ni siquiera la página inicial del servidor.
Si utilizo un servidor Tomcat, si me reconoce y abre por lo menos el index, pero debido a la funcionalidad de la misma no me deja otra opción que utilizar un servidor de aplicaciones. No sé si hay alguna configuración que tengo que hacer en el HOME del servidor o algo por el estilo. Agradecería mucho la ayuda!

Comment: ¿Cómo pones en marcha el Wildfly?

Comment: voy al JBOSS_HOME, luego bin y luego levanto con standalone.bat

Comment: otra cosa interesante para comentar es que al intentar acceder desde mi pc con mi url, 190.10.12.35:8080 no reconoce, únicamente colocando localhost:8080

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por defecto -creo que por motivos de seguridad-, JBoss/WildFly sólo hace el *binding* de los puertos para la IP de localhost.

Para levantarlo de forma que haga el *binding* con otra IP de la máquina, hay que pasarle la IP (ya sea por el bat/sh de configuración, ya sea por parámetro).

Desde línea de comando sería

```
standalone.bat -b 190.10.12.35
```

Si en vez de la IP pasas `0.0.0.0`, se levanta para todas las IPs de la máquina. Es lo que suelo hacer yo (así no hay problema si accedes por localhost).

[Más detalles aquí](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Command+line+parameters), aunque estén en un idioma desconocido...

Comment: Antes que nada gracias por la molestia. Levantando el servidor de esa manera al hacer 190.10.12.35:8080 abre bien la página de bienvenida al servidor, pero no me deja ir al Administration Console y tampoco me abre el la página inicial de mi proyecto, me imprime en la página Internal Server Error.

Comment: Ah! Pero la consola tiene su propio *binding*, y necesitas hacer `-bmanagement=0.0.0.0` (o tu IP, o ir a localhost). Y por defecto está en el puerto 9990. En cuanto a tu aplicación, eso ya dependerá de tu código, del log que esté mostrando, etc. etc., y creo que será cuestión de tratarlo como una cuestión aparte.

Comment: Gracias amigo, me sirvió bastante. Para complementar la respuesta, dentro del archivo standalone.xml se debe modificar el jboss.bind.address:190.10.12.35 (con la dirección del server), al igual que el jboss.bind.address.management, y el jboss.bind.address.unsecure. Con esto más tu aporte me funcionó de maravilla.

Comment: Cuidado, como explica el link que puse, lo único que hacen los parámetros `-b` es cambiar el valor de variables de entorno que luego se usan en `standalone.xml`. Si cambias `standalone.xml` para que no use las variables de entorno (por ejemplo, poniendo la IP "a piñón fijo"), entonces los parámetros `-b` ya no sirven para nada. O dicho de otra forma, los parámetros `-b` son para pasar el valor que quieres al `standalone.xml` sin necesidad de modificar éste.

Comment: Excelente. muchas gracias!